# Finding item frequency in list of lists

Tags: python, frequency, apriori

Let's say I have a list of lists and I want to find the frequency in which pairs (or more) of elements appears in total.

For example, if i have [[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[c,d,e]

I want :(a,b) = 1, (b,c) = 2, (c,d) = 2, etc.

I tried finding a usable apriori algorithm that would allow me to do this, but i couldn't find a easy to implement one in python.

How would I approach this problem in a better way?

Comment: So you want to count the number of times an item appears in a list of lists?

Comment: What's stpping you from implementing the apriori algorithm on wikipedia?  The only thing i see there without an obvious python equivalent is a multiset, which you can use `collection.Counter` for.

Comment: Do the sub-lists always have three items?

Comment: yeah all sublists have the same length, 5 items actually.

Comment: Does the order matter or you want permutations, For example in `[a,b,c]`, `(a, b) =1` and `(b,c) = 1` what about `(a,c)`? Should that be present too or not?

Comment: order doesnt matter, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [['a','b','c'],['b','c','d'],['c','d','e']]
d = {}
for i in l:
    # for every item on l take all the possible combinations of 2
    comb = combinations(i, 2)
    for c in comb:
        k = ''.join(c)
        if d.get(k):
            d[k] += 1
        else:
            d[k] = 1
```

Result:

```
>>> d
{'bd': 1, 'ac': 1, 'ab': 1, 'bc': 2, 'de': 1, 'ce': 1, 'cd': 2}
```